# How to display an inline image generated on the fly using PHP GD

Tags: php, gd

I am trying the generate an image on the fly by merging images using PHP GD. I want to know if there is a way I can display the image inside my webpage without the need of storing it somewhere on server.

Like for example I created the following code for merging the images...

```
function create_image() {
   $main_image = imagecreatefrompng("images/main.png");
   $other_image = imagecreatefrompng("images/other.png");
   imagecopy($main_image, $other_image, 114, 53, 0, 0, 49, 34);
   imagepng($main_image);
   imagedestroy($other_image);
}
```

Now my html code till now was...

```
<div class="sidebar-avatar">
   <img src="avatar_pattern.png" class="pattern1" width="430" height="100" />
</div>
```

How should I call the php function so that it displays the image generated in the div I have designated for it.

**Update**: I found the use of `Content-type: image/png` but that would mean I will have to display the image on a separate page not inline.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Convert it to Base64 with base64_encode and echo it as a dataURI in an img tag !

[Inline Images with Data URLs](http://www.websiteoptimization.com/speed/tweak/inline-images/)

Comment: ... and be very aware of size limits, and browser support.  Generally, this isn't a good idea, but Aweb's answer here is perfectly correct.

Answer (score 4):

You can either:

1. Display the image as data: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme (Warning: High bandwidth consumption.)
2. Make a separate file that display the image, such as display_image.php

And use the code:

```
<img src="display_image.php">
```

With the header and code you have shown.

Comment: The second idea seems the best to me, that's what I did int eh past. You just have to use GET or SESSION to store your data, for instance.

Answer (score 1):

`<img src="image.php?other_image=(filename)">`

and create your image in image.php, output with

```
header('Content-Type:image/png');imagepng($main_image);
```

---

You can also put the image creation part in the same script:

```
if($other_image=$_GET['other_image'])
{
    // create image
    ...
    // output image
    header('Content-Type:image/png');
    imagepng($main_image);
}
else
{
    // default behaviour
    ...
    echo '<img src="',basename(__FILE__),'?other_image=',urlencode('images/other.png'),'">';
    ...
}
```

---

**Take care to prevent injections!**